# Comparing an int initialization with a boolean operator for an if statement parameter

Tags: java, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I've declared ints **skyB** and **day**, and written this line:

```
if (skyB == true || (day=1) != true) {
System.out.print("example text");  
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that the code will properly execute the argument given these parameters? I'm specifically unsure about whether or not the (day="1") would be properly *detected* as false, given the instance that the objects input was indeed a false.

minimal reproducable example(not including main method or packages):

```
 int skyB = false;

 int day =2;

 if (skyB == true || (day =1) != true) {
System.out.print("example text");  }
```

Comment: Instead of comparing two ints, you're comparing an int to a boolean, and assigning a string to an int. Won't even compile.

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: If you are unsure try it by writing unit tests.

Comment: I can't test the code myself as I am on a slower PC that can't handle a JDK, but this my CS homework

Comment: Initializing an int with false or a string doesn’t make an sense.

Comment: yeah, i'm just initializing it as a boolean value, it's not in parenthesis, therefore it's not a string value.

Comment: Day is initialized as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer: this isn't C++

You cannot assign numeric value to boolean fields. In Java, the only two valid values are `true` and `false`. Therefore, you cannot assign integer values to a boolean variable.

For your boolean expressions to be valid, your variables `skyB` and `day` must be `boolean` data types

```
boolean skyB = false
boolean day = true

if (!skyB || day) {
  System.out.print("example text");
}
```

The `boolean` fields are evaluated without the need to compare them to true or false. The expression `!skyB` (read "not skyB") evaluates to `false`. So this is the equivalent to `skyB == false`. Since that portion evaluates to true (skyB is equal to false), the second part of the expression is skipped and the `System.out.print()` is called. If the value of `skyB` was changed to true, the variable `day` would then be evaluated and the if-statement would be executed if the value of that variable equals true (which it is).

Alternatively, you could build boolean expressions using numeric values. How? Simple. Any mathematical expression is evaluated the same. For example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 3;

if (x > y) {
  System.out.println("x is greater than y");
}
```

Basically... The logic of what you are trying to do (the way I understood it) is correct, but your implementation was not. You cannnot mix boolean fields and numeric values. It is simply not allowed in Java.

Now, to your question...

```
boolean skyB = false; // this must be boolean, not int
int day =2;       // this is fine

if (skyB || day == 1) {
  System.out.print("example text");
}
```

Should produce the desired outcome. In plain English, the above is read:

> If skyB is false OR is day one, print "example test"

If either part of the expression fails to evaluate to true (i.e. if skyB is true and day variable is any value other than one), it will not print anything.

**UPDATE**:

Even if this answer has been accepted and upvoted, I would like to include some information about boolean expressions for the benefit of new developers that might be struggling with this concept.

> What is a Boolean Expression?

According to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/olap.101/b10339/expression006.htm), "*A Boolean expression is a logical statement that is either TRUE or FALSE.*" These expressions take a few different forms. For example,

- ***Boolean literals***

```
if (true) {...}
```

Although there is no real reason for such if-statement, the above is a valid expression. "If true, do the stuff inside the curly braces." This means that the stuff inside will always execute (making it the same as not having the "if". However, this is the basis for understanding the rest.

- ***Boolean variables***

```
boolean isBlue = false;
if (isBlue) {...}
```

In the above case, the Boolean expression is the variable itself. The expectation is that, if the variable value evaluates to `true`, the stuff inside the curly braces will be executed. Since the value is false, it won't be executed. The above "if" is the more accepted short form of

```
boolean isBlue = false;
if (isBlue == true) {...}
```

So, since the left hand (variable) value of this evaluation is false and the right side is true, the complete expression evaluates to false. Therefore, the stuff inside curly braces won't be executed (false does not equals true). However

```
boolean isBlue = false;
if(!isBlue == true){...}
```

Negating a boolean variable toggles it's value. In this case, the `isBlue` variable holds the value of `false`. The "not" operator toggles its value to `true`. Since `true == true` evaluates to true (true equals true is a true expression), the stuff inside curly braces is executed.

- ***Functions that yield a boolean value***

```
public boolean isSkyBlue() {
  return true; // sorry for the over simplification
}
...
if (isSkyBlue()) {...}
```

This is nothing more than an advance form of what I have shown already. In this case, the method "computes" the boolean value to be returned. Since boolean values are expressions onto themselves, it is valid to insert a method call such as the one illustrated above inside the parentheses. The stuff inside curly braces will execute so long the function returns `true`.

- ***Comparison operations***

I included the following example already:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 3;

if (x > y) {
  System.out.println("x is greater than y");
}
```

Any type of comparison operation will yield true or false. Therefore, these comparison operations are boolean expressions. This also includes the result of overridden `Object#equals(Object)` method. For example:

```
String s = "Hello";
if (s.equals("Hello")) {...}
```

As a side note, objects in Java should be compared using an overridden `equals()` method, and not using the double-equals operator (unless you are only interested in comparing the object references (address) to be equal.

Comment: Thank you very much, that cleared up my question. quick follow up, I was basically trying to ask if it was day 1, out of a list of days 1-7, without constraining myself to booleans. would the only way to feasibly do that be to nest my if statements for each day of the week? my assignment is to use boolean operators.

Comment: how would return a value from a list to check as an if statement parameter, basically?

Comment: @CarsonTurner I answered your primary question. If you are satisfied with the answer I provided, click the check to select as the correct answer. As to your last comment, that is a separate question altogether. You must post another question for that. I would be glad to help you with that one as well.